# Why am i getting this error? binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I don't know why I'm getting this compile error. I tried the usual way to define strings and i also tries std::string but neither worked. Also I think there might be a problem with how I'm trying to print the function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

float userInput1() // Defines the inputs from the user
{
using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter first number" << endl;
    float number1;
    cin >> number1;

    return number1;
}

float userInput2() // Defines the inputs from the user
{
using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter second number" << endl;
    float number2;
    cin >> number2;

    return number2;
}

std::string getOperation()
{
using namespace std;
    cout<<"Please enter the operator. + - * /" << endl;
    std::string userOperator;
    cin>>userOperator;

    return userOperator;
}

float computeValue(float value1, float value2, std::string operation)
{
using namespace std;

    if(operation == '+')
    {
        cout<< value1 + value2<< endl;
    }else if(operation =='-')
    {
        cout<< value1 - value2<< endl;
    }else if(operation =='*')
    {
        cout<< value1 * value2<< endl;
    }else if(operation == '/')
    {
        cout<< value1 / value2<< endl;
    }else
    {
        cout<< "Please enter: + - * /"<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){
using namespace std;

    computeValue(userInput1(), userInput2(), getOperation());

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing `std::string` with a `char` value using the `==` operator. The standard library does not define an equality operator between those two types. The list of valid comparisons is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/

The simplest way is to convert the `char` values into `char*` by using `"` instead of `'`, like so:

```
 if(operation == '+')
```

becomes

```
 if(operation == "+")
```

Comment: `"+"` decays to a `const char*`, not a `char*`.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a reliable source. And the types that can be compared cannot be exhaustively enumerated, because user-defined conversions are followed. If a non-`explicit` `std::string::string(char)` constructor were defined, the comparison would work. In fact, in C++11, `operator == ( operation, { '+' } )` would work, although using an expression of `==` would not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! It worked!!
Whats the difference between string and char. Also why is it that I have to use `"` rather than simply a `'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're comparing the string object to a character in your `computeValue`  function. There no overload of `operator ==` in the std namespace which takes both a `std::string` and a `char`, hence the error.

You should be using `char` instead of a `std::string` if you only need a character as input.

```
char getOperation()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the operator. + - * /" << std::endl;
    char userOperator;
    std::cin >> userOperator;

    return userOperator;
}
```

Your parameter should also take a `char`:

```
float computeValue(float value1, float value2, char operation)
//                                              ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!
My question is why didn't this work with a string and why how did it take a string and a char. I only declared `strings` in my code
@0x499602D2